Would it be legal to make videos on publicly available textbooks?
Suppose a textbook exists in the public domain, then would it be legal to make publicly available youtube  videos on working through it and it's problems?
In particular I am thinking of this

A work really in the public domain
Suppose you want to make a video about De analysi per aequationes numero terminorum infinitas, which is in the Public Domain, then you can do that, because Public Domain means everybody has rights to use and alter the work as they want.
The linked work is not in the Public Domain
However, the script linked to was made in or around 2022, the author is alive and German Copyright Law applies. Accessibility by the public does not remove any rights of the author or put the work in the Public Domain (Gemeinfreiheit). In Germany (and most other western Berne Convention on Copyright Countries) that happens only 70 years after the author's death for a published work like the lecture script. As such, You either need an Exception from Copyright or a License.
In Germany, among the exceptions you have, among others, the right to Cite the work, or to use it as part of Teaching and Education - BUT there are strict limits on the latter, and obligations to follow. Obtaining a written License or Allowance (Genehmigung) can massively open the scope of what you may do legally.
As such, the work is not in the public domain, and the German copyright laws have to be followed, especially §51 & §60a-h UrHG.
